# How does one revert multiple changes in a branch prior to the head but all from the same child branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Sprint Branch (`Sprint1`) Composed of Multiple Feature Branches (listed newest to oldest):

- Feature4, Commit #1
- Feature3, Commit #2
- Feature3, Commit #1
- Feature2, Commit #3
- Feature2, Commit #2
- Feature2, Commit #1
- Feature1, Commit #1

I want to remove everything from the Sprint Branch that's come from Feature #2's Branch in a single operation.  Is there a way I can do this?

In reality I have a lot more than 3 commits on Feature #2 and don't want to have to revert them one-by-one in case I miss a commit.  I am going to have a lot of merge conflicts to resolve since Features #3 and #4 were built upon Feature #2 and now need to be independent.  I just want to pull out Feature #2 and resolve all the merge conflicts in one go.

As requested by RomainValeri, the following is the result of running `git log --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --all` from my `Sprint1` branch:

```
f12b0af (HEAD -> Sprint1) Merge of Feature #3 and Feature #4.
70c028b (Feature3) Feature #3, Commit #2
216764a (Feature4) Feature #4, Commit #1
060d98e (Feature2) Feature #2, Commit #3
2069da0 (Feature1) Feature#1 Commit #1
1d05fc0 (master) First Commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume names here : `sprint` for the sprint branch, and you try to revert all from `feature2` branch.

```
# next line was my first idea but probably no good
git rev-list $(git merge-base sprint feature2)..feature2

# since we have master as a ref for the merge-base, let's go simpler
git rev-list master..feature2

# or, if feature2 is branched of feature1 :
git rev-list feature1..feature2
```

will give you the list of commits to revert.

(If you already deleted `feature2`, just recreate it at the commit just before the merge into `sprint`, or get it from the reflog)

Then you can chain reverts without committing and commit just once at the end :

```
git revert -n <commit1>
git revert -n <commit2>
...
git commit -m "Revert of commits 1, 2, 3, ..."
```

But I wouldn't automate the process further since you'll probably have to resolve conflicts along the way.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the first script; I tried `git rev-list $(git merge-base Sprint1 Feature2)..Feature2` (where Sprint1 is the name of the sprint branch from which all feature branches are derived) and the GIT Terminal returned nothing!  I tried taking off the `..Feature2` part of the script (as I've never seen the `..` syntax before) and instead of nothing, it returned 100s of lines of GUIDs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A bit tricky to assume things "in the dark". Could you edit your question with the output of a `git log --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --all`. I might have overlooked something in your setting. If the tree is massive and output is too long, try to add `-20`, more or less, to focus on where feature2 is branched of and merged.

Comment: I've created a test repository to reflect this question and the result is the same as on my real repository for the `git rev-list ...` script you provided.  I've updated my question to include the result of the last script you sent.

Comment: @MattArnold In fact, since we have a named ref for the merge-base (`master`), far simpler to go with it (I've edited).

Comment: I ran `git rev-list master..Feature2` and again just got GUIDs.  I don't know what these represent but I got 5 of them when I would have expected 3 if they're representing the commits made in the Feature#2 branch.  Also, I didn't realize `master` was going to be relevant in all of this so I didn't bother deriving `Sprint1` from `Development` which is derived from `UAT` which is then derived from `master` in the actual repository - does this affect the solution?  Why is `master` the base when I'm only reverting changes made on `Sprint1` via `Feature2`?  I was expecting `Sprint1` to be the base.

Comment: But if I understood well, `Feature2` is already merged into your `Sprint1`, right? So their merge-base won't help us. We need to point to the most recent commit that `Feature2` shares with the branch it originated from.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, `Feature2` is merged into `Sprint1`.  The most recent commit (excluding its own commits) that `Feature2` shares with the branch it originated from (`Sprint1`) would be Commit #1 of `Feature1` - but if you point to this then what happens to the commits of `Feature3` and `Feature4` (which have also been merged into `Sprint1`)?

Comment: `a..b` means "everything reachable from b that is NOT already reachable from a", so commits of features 3 and 4, which are not reachable from the commits in feature2, are out of the scope if you have `master..feature2`. In fact, the first part of the expression must be the commit (not the branch) where feature2 branched of. Yes, at the time, Sprint1 was the branch pointing at this commit, but now that Sprint1 has advanced, we can't use that.

Comment: Ah, that does follow based on a mistake I've just seen I made.  I ran `git rev-list master Feature2` and got 5 GUIDs instead of `git rev-list master..Feature2` which gave me 4 GUIDs.  I'm guessing the 4 GUIDs are `Feature1`'s Commit #1 then `Feature2`'s Commits #1 to #3.  So do I have to manually, and carefully, use only the GUIDs that represent `Feature2` listed from the `git rev-list master..Feature2` command when running `git revert -n <commit1>` (where `<commit1>` is presumably the GUID of Commit #3 of `Feature2` (since don't commits have to be reverted in reverse chronological order?))?

Comment: Yes, that's the plan, it sounds like you got the picture. The operation is tricky, so first try on a mockup branch. Create a new branch from feature2 and apply the reverts here. If after applying all the reverts you have the end result you wanted, merge this new branch into your sprint1. If not, just trash it and try another way without having done further harm.